# How to limit data returned by Firestore's onSnapshot listener?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In the context of react-native chat application project, I'm using 
`firebase.firestore().collection("conversations").where("members", "array-contains", {email}).onSnapshot( ... )`. 
This listener is located in my inbox's `componentDidMount()`

Every time the app launches, the entire result set of the query is returned, even if there is nothing new. How can I limit the results of this listener to only what has changed from the last time it read from firestore? I've looked into `redux-persist`, but I'm not sure how that would limit the result set of `onSnapshot`.

The main goal is to minimize a potentially extreme Firebase bill. if it cant be done with onSnapshot, what are some other options that maintain realtime functionality? I'm aware the realtime database charges for storage instead of reads/writes/deletes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Migrating to firebase's realtime database is unnecessary. in worst case scenario (screens with large amounts of data), major firestore-read-savings can be had with the combination of redux-persist and this firestore query:

```
export const inboxLoadTest = (email, startAfter) => {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch({ type: types.INBOX_LOADING });
    firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("conversations")
      .where("members", "array-contains", email)
      .orderBy("lastMsgTime")
      .startAfter([startAfter])
      .onSnapshot(
        querySnapshot => {
          let conversations = [];
          querySnapshot.forEach(queryDocumentSnapshot => {
            const membersArr = queryDocumentSnapshot.get("members");
            let conversation = {
              id: queryDocumentSnapshot.id,
              conversant:
                membersArr[0] === email ? membersArr[1] : membersArr[0],
              lastMsgTime: queryDocumentSnapshot.get("lastMsgTime")
            };
            conversations.push(conversation);
          });
          dispatch(loadInboxSuccess(conversations));
        },
        errorObject => {
          dispatch(loadInboxError(errorObject.message));
        }
      );
  };
};
```

Once data is loaded, `redux-persist` will save to asyncstorage so on app re-load, the above listener will only fire for messages received after the last message stored in redux/asyncstorage, instead of the entire collection of messages, saving on the result set, and thus the firebase billing